# Byte Array Switch Statement C#

Tags: c#, arrays, switch-statement

I am writing the content of a byte array to both the screen and a text file using the for loops below. The 3rd column in the array relates to attributes and rather than displaying the attribute number I want to add a switch statement that takes the given number and swaps it with text.

```
foreach (ManagementObject FailData in FailDataSet)
{
    Byte[] data =(Byte[])FailData.Properties["VendorSpecific"].Value;
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < data[0] - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++)
        {  
            richTextBox2.Text = richTextBox2.Text + data[i * 12 + j] + "\t";
            sb.Append(data[i * 12 + j] + "\t");
        }
        richTextBox2.Text = richTextBox2.Text + "\n";
        sb.AppendLine();
    }
    String title = "Unknw\tUnknw\tAttribute\tStatus\tUnknw\tValue\tWorst\tRaw\t\tUnknw\r\n";
    File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\Desktop\WriteText1.txt", title + sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: your array has 1 dimension, what do you mean by 3rd column?

Comment: Can't you just define an array with your string values? Place them in position that equals byte value. And then extract string value from array by index.

Comment: Apologies.... When the data is written in the 12 byte blocks the 3rd column displayed is the attribute

Comment: Why don't you just populate the `StringBuilder` and in the end assign it to the `Textbox`? You are unnecessarily constantly updating it.

Comment: `data[0]` has the number of groups of 12 elements that array has + 1? Where is the text that corresponds to each attribute number? Do you have an enum or something?

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it:

```
foreach (ManagementObject FailData in FailDataSet)
{
    Byte[] data =(Byte[])FailData.Properties["VendorSpecific"].Value;
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < data[0] - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++)
        {  
            string text = data[i * 12 + j];
            if (j == 2)
                text = GetText(text);
            sb.Append(text + "\t");
        }
        sb.AppendLine();
    }
    richTextBox2.Text = sb.ToString();
    String title = "Unknw\tUnknw\tAttribute\tStatus\tUnknw\tValue\tWorst\tRaw\t\tUnknw\r\n";
    File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\Desktop\WriteText1.txt", title + sb.ToString());
}
```

*Note that there is a missing closing parenthesis in your code in the last line.*

And the function could be something like this:

```
private string GetText(string numberText)
{
    int number;
    if (!int.TryParse(numberText, out number))
        return string.Empty; // or "invalid" or whatever

    switch (number)
    {
        case 1: return "one";
        case 2: return "two";
        default: return "other";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the format of your `byte[]` is as follows:

> - [0]: count of rows of data (plus 1, really?)
> - [1]..[12]: first row of data
> - [13]..[24]: second row of data
> - etc.

If so, then the first thing I'll point out is that you have a bug in your program. You are indexing the data starting at the element at index 0, but of course that has the row count. You should be adding 1 to your computed index to account for that.

Also, while it's possible that the row count in the data is actually the number of rows plus 1, requiring the subtraction of 1 for your row counter loop comparison, it seems more plausible that's simply yet another bug in the code.

Taking those things into account, it sounds like what you want is something like this:

```
foreach (ManagementObject FailData in FailDataSet)
{
    Byte[] data =(Byte[])FailData.Properties["VendorSpecific"].Value;
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < data[0]; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++)
        {
            int dataIndex = i * 12 + j + 1;
            string textForColumn = j == 2 ?
                GetAttributeText(data[dataIndex]) : data[dataIndex].ToString();

            richTextBox2.Text = richTextBox2.Text + textForColumn + "\t";
            sb.Append(textForColumn + "\t");
        }
        richTextBox2.Text = richTextBox2.Text + "\n";
        sb.AppendLine();
    }
    String title = "Unknw\tUnknw\tAttribute\tStatus\tUnknw\tValue\tWorst\tRaw\t\tUnknw\r\n";
    File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\Desktop\WriteText1.txt", title + sb.ToString();
}
```

where:

```
static string GetAttributeText(byte value)
{
    switch (value)
    {
    case 0:
        return "First Attribute Text";
    case 1:
        return "Second Attribute Text";
    case 2:
        return "Third Attribute Text";
    default:
        return "<unknown attribute>";
    }
}
```

Note that opinions vary on the readability of a `switch` statement. The above could also be achieved using a dictionary:

```
static readonly Dictionary<byte, string> _byteToAttributeText =
    new Dictionary<byte, string>()
    {
        { 0, "First Attribute Text" },
        { 1, "Second Attribute Text" },
        { 2, "Third Attribute Text" },
    };

static string GetAttributeText(byte value)
{
    string text;

    if (!_byteToAttributeText.TryGetValue(value, out text))
    {
        return "<unknown attribute>";
    }

    return text;
}
```